# Rich text in Debug message in Unity console

Tags: unity, c#

I'm currently writing a debug script and would like to add colors to certain parts of the debug messages. Reading the unity docs lead me to believe that I can use the Rich text formatting. Like it is explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html). I'm using the `Debug.LogForamt()`.

> Logs a formatted message to the Unity Console.
>
> For formatting details, see the MSDN documentation on Composite
>   Formatting. Rich text markup can be used to add emphasis.

This is from the unity docs. My code looks like this :

```
Debug.LogFormat("Status of some gameObject is : <color = red>{0}</color>" +
"Status of another gameObjcet is: <color = red>{1}</color>",
gameObject1.activeInHierarchy,gameObject2.activeInHierarchy);
```

This just outpust the strings as plain text. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: same question is [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176292/can-i-show-logs-in-unity-with-different-colors-or-different-icon-signs/176302#176302).you can use [Kamali Debug](https://github.com/smkplus/KamaliDebug)

Comment: Try this extension, it will make it so much easier! https://forum.unity.com/threads/easy-text-format-your-debug-logs-rich-text-format.906464/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove the extra spaces and / or set the color in hex format?

```
Debug.LogFormat("Status of some gameObject is : <color=#ff0000ff>{0}</color>" + "Status of another gameObjcet is: <color=#ff0000ff>{1}</color>", gameObject1.activeInHierarchy,gameObject2.activeInHierarchy);
```

Comment: Yes! Both tries yielded the same result.

Comment: restarting unity fixed it X_X. As always.